# Calculate time to impact on elipisoid Earth

Tags: orbital-mechanics, mathematics, astrodynamics

As a simple project to introduce myself to orbital mechanics I'm attempting to calculate impact times of an object close to Earth. Right now I am using only Keplerian mechanics (no air resistance or other perturbing forces). From [Fundamentals of Astrodynamics](http://www.amazon.ca/Fundamentals-Astrodynamics-Roger-R-Bate/dp/0486600610), given an object with eccentric anomaly $E_0$ at $t_0$ and $E_1$ at $t_1$:

$$t_1 = t_0 + \sqrt{\frac{a^3}{\mu}}\left( E_1 - e\sin E_1 - (E_0 - e\sin E_0)\right)$$

where $a$ is the semi-major axis, $e$ is the eccentricity, and $\mu$ is the gravitational parameter. We can then calculate the radius of the periapsis. Assuming a spherical Earth, if this is less than the radius of the Earth the object will impact. If this is the case, letting $r_1 = R = $ Earth radius, we can calculate the eccentric anomalies at $t_0$ and $t_1$ using:

$$ \cos\nu_i =\frac{a(1 - e^2) - r_i}{e r_i}$$ 
$$ \cos E_i = \frac{e + cos\nu_i}{1 + e\cos\nu_i}$$

where $\nu_i$ is the true anomaly, and $r_i$ is the distance from the centre of the Earth at $t_i$. This method works well for non-parabolic trajectories (I'm open to modifications for parabolic trajectories).

The next step is to loosen the restriction of a spherical Earth and allow Earth to be an ellipsoid, in other words let $R = R(z)$ (symmetric around rotational axis). Specifically I'd like to allow for a bulge at the equator by prescribing an equatorial radius, a polar radius and an eccentricity. Is it possible to solve this problem analytically or does it have to be done numerically?

This is my first post on this stack exchange; I felt it was better suited here than scicomp for example. If that's not the case please let me know.

Comment: A near-Earth object will be on a hyperbolic trajectory with respect to Earth, so you can't use these equations, which are for something in orbit around Earth.

Comment: Not necessarily, you could have something like an ICBM for example.

Comment: As an aside, do you feel that book is worth picking up? I focused on history, law, management, etc. in my space related degree (with little focus on else), but I'm always interested in branching out.

Comment: Yeah definitely! It's really well written and it covers a wide range of topics from basic orbits to interplanetary trajectories. Each section goes over the history of the methods being used; something I found really interesting. The only downside is that it was written in the 1970s, so it's somewhat out of date, but hey, it was good enough to get us to the moon.

Comment: If you allow an ellipsoid Earth, you will get orbits where an object will either hit or miss the Earth depending on where in its rotational period Earth is. So you've added a dimension to your problem.

Comment: I had assumed that by near-Earth object, you meant a [Near-Earth Object](http://neo.jpl.nasa.gov/).

Comment: @MarkAdler, Sorry, I'll edit the question to make that more clear.

Comment: @Hobbes Maybe it's not clear in the question, but my ellipsoid will still be symmetric around the axis of rotation (just a bulging equator) so I don't think the rotational period of Earth matters (ignoring nutation and precession).

Comment: I'd vote for doing it numerically but that's what I'm used to doing.

Comment: I do assume that you do not restrict the problem to only equatorial inclinations, since you would be able to use Kepler orbits with a correction factor for the gravitational parameter. Also do you assume homogeneous density, or would the center be more dense, like Earth?

Comment: You have not sufficiently described your problem.  If your orbit is in the plane of the equator, then it is no different than the spherical problem, just using the equatorial radius.  Is the orbit inclined?  Is it rotated about the line of apsides?  Is it rotated about the perpendicular to the orbit plane?

Comment: @MarkAdler I'm not placing any restrictions on the orbit, in fact I'd like to be able to calculate the impact times for parabolas and hyperbolas as well, but that's probably a slightly different problem, so I'd accept answers specific to any ellipse.

Comment: @fibonatic in fact I'm just interested in the very simplified case of just having a bulging equator, ignoring any gravitational perturbations caused by it. This means we can still have Earth as a point mass (assuming uniform density).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the general case you will need to solve numerically for the radii at which the orbit intersects the ellipsoid.  Then you can solve analytically for the times at which the orbit is at those radii.  That is, if you ignore $J_2$.  Since you made it an ellipsoid, you have introduced a $J_2$, so you will no longer be in a Keplerian orbit.  To take $J_2$ into account, the times would then also need to be solved for numerically.